# Frozen/stucked OS and no signal from Graphics Card after programming a script with Chrome Dev Console

Tags: windows, hard-drive, graphics-card, freeze

Well the problem started yesterday and now I'm a little bit scared.

Everything started when I was coding some Javascript code in the Chrome Dev Console.

I listen too often Spotify and while I was coding I heard like ticks. I thought that was something related to the Chrome interface but I wasn't sure because I didn't heard that before.

At 6 am before I go sleep I returned back to computer to finish what I was doing. And well, when I started playing the music again, suddenly the sound from Spotify became very laggy and distorted. I pressed the Windows key to open menu to try to shutdown my computer but even the Windows menu was unresponsive and it didn't opened at all (I only saw how the menu tried to open (it was fading) before I turned off my computer by pressing the power off button)

Today I started the computer again and when I opened Chrome the screen turned black for a few seconds and recovered. The happened three times before the screen didn't have signal again (I pressed again the power off button). I powered again the computer and I tried to update my drivers but after that I opened Firefox and the screen went black again. So I needed to turn off again the computer pressing the button.

I have removed the graphics card and I'm now using chkdsk utility because CrystalDisk told me that there was 7 "realocated sectors" damaged and my hard drive was in risk.

I have two storage devices (a 250GB Samsung Evo SSD (where I have my OS) and  a 2TB Toshiba HDD where I store everything else)).

Talking with some guys in Telegram they told me that this can be caused by a PSU problem (I have a 750W Tacens Vulcano PSU). And well, they told me that this PSU is so good. So I'm having doubts.

I'm very worried and scared because blue screens scares me too much and more when I'm listening music I hate this awful glitchy and stucked sound from music when this happens.

I don't know what I should do now. I'm looking in Amazon to buy a new HDD to make a backup and do a low level format of my damaged one.

But I'm still worried because I'm not sure at all if the problem is related to my HDD or something worse.

Because, first, my graphics card is a second hand one (can a faulty graphics card damage any component? How can I check its health status?). Second, in Christmas there was several light cuts in my home, so I could imagine that the "allocated sectors" problem is related to this, but I'm not sure. Third and the most important question, following your experience what more can I check from my computer and what do you think it's related to?

Comment: What version of Windows? Have you tried getting into safe mode?

Comment: I have Windows 10 (I think I have April update) I don't tried safe mode. Without the graphics card everything (by the moment) is fine. But I'm unsure if the problem is related with the graphics card. This is why I'm worried, because I didn't use my pc as I normally use it.